# src not changing on else if part of if/else statement

Tags: javascript

I have created a function which is used in an event listener function so when the user clicks the left arrow icon on the webpage, a different character image is displayed. The first click works fine and the image is changed, however on the second click, nothing happens. I can't figure out why as from what I can see, the condition of the 'else if' of the statement is true so therefore the src code should change accordingly and change the image.

There are no error messages in the console.

Here is the Event listener:

```
  document.querySelector(".left").addEventListener("click", () => {
            leftArrow();
        });
```

Here is the leftArrow function:

```
leftArrow: () => {
      if (document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg).src = characters[0]) {
        document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg).classList.add("boris");
        document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg).src = characters[1];
        const el = document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg);
        console.log(el);
      } else if (document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg).src = characters[1]) {
        document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg).classList.remove("boris");
        document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg).src = characters[0];

        const el = document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg);
        console.log(el);

      }
```

Here is where the images are stored:

```
const characters = ["Resources/Images/trump.png", "Resources/Images/boris.png"];
```

Here is where the DOM strings are stored:

```
const DOMstrings = {
    characterImg: ".character-img"
}
```

Lastly, here is the relevant html:

```
<div class="character-select">
                <ion-icon class="left" name="arrow-dropleft-circle"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon class="right" name="arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon>
                <img class="character-img" src="Resources/Images/trump.png">        
            </div>
```

Comment: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.characterImg).src = characters[0] is asigmnet, use == or ====

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` or `===` tests for equality

Comment: can you please add value of DOMStrings.characterImg

Comment: You shouldn't use `=`, it is an assignment, instead use `== `or `===`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/hackanm.gif"; 
}

function myFunctionbygeneric(){
   document.querySelector(".test").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/hackanm.gif";
}
function myFunctionbygenericid(){
   document.querySelector("#myImg").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif";
   }
```

```html
<img id="myImg" class="test" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif" width="107" height="98">
<button onclick="myFunction()">click here</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionbygenericid()">Query selector by id</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionbygeneric()">Query selector</button>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this thank you! Unfortunately, now even the first click isn't working and the image is not changing. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnDev I couldn't reproduce it based on your issue but added code for your reference. Please run the above code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use can use like this

```js
let myImage = document.querySelector('img');

myImage.onclick = function() {
    let mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    if(mySrc === 'https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif') {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/hackanm.gif');
    } else {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif');
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/hackanm.gif" />
```